# Dosbox create aliases

Tags: dos, dosbox

Hi is there a way how to create an alias for a command in dosbox?
I have found something that is called 4dos but I'm looking for some simpler way

The think what I want is make ls act like dir or i have a dos program which i use in dosbox and i want to be able to start it from any directory without writing its path explicitly or copying it into that directory.

The programs I want to use in dosbox are
`TASM`
`TLINK`

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You can create a .bat file with the command you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create batch files (`.bat`) that do whatever you like, put them in some directory, and put that directory in the `PATH` (using `set`).

Putting the directory in the `PATH` is also the way to make `dosbox` search for a program even if it is not in the current directory.

Comment: Example: I created a drive B:, created a directory in B: called `commands`, and placed my `.bat` files in there. In my DOSBox autoexec, I placed this after my mount command: `set PATH=%PATH%;b:\commands`. My custom `.bat` commands now run from everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a program called `doskey.com`.
You can define an alias `ls` for `dir` with

```
doskey ls=dir
```

Comment: Seems DOSBox does not have this command preinstalled. Any idea how to obtain it?

Comment: @aggregate1166877 doskey.com is part of archive.org's _dosdrivers_ collection: https://archive.org/details/dosdrivers

Comment: +1 for the archive, this will definitely come in very handy. I tried now however, and doskey unfortunately does not seem to work with DOSBox in this context - I get a `DOSKEY installed` message, but the alias does not actually take effect. When invoking the alias I get `Illegal command: ll`. DOSBox does have some weird internals, it's possible this command simply can't work here.